# Remove top and bottom margins around listings

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, spacing, listings

When using the `lstlisting` environment, or similar ones from the `listings` package, there are paragraph-like margins above and below the actual text.  This makes sense in a paper, but gets in the way if you try to put code inside a Tikz node (e.g., for a Beamer presentation):

```
 \node[inner sep=1mm, text width=6cm, draw=green, line width=2pt, rounded corners]
  {%
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible]{alt1.java} 
  };
```

[image: listing with margins]

(Do ignore the question of why I put this jumbled code in a node...)

As you can see there are top and bottom margins that add extra redundant space to the node.

How can I remove these margins?  I suppose it is some `lstset` option, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space above and below the listing can be set using `aboveskip` and `belowskip`. The default value is `\medskipamount`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}
\tikz \node[inner sep=1mm, text width=6cm, draw=green, line width=2pt, rounded corners]
  {%
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible, breaklines=true,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt]{data.txt} 
  };   
\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to solve most of the problem.  There's still some small space left, although much narrower.  Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Remove the `inner sep=1mm` from the `\node` option keys.